# How can I hide the "Title" while maintaining the "Title" value when mouse over "google maps Marker"?

Tags: javascript

How can I hide the "Title" while maintaining the "Title" value when mouse over "google maps Marker"?
I'm using "Label" instead of "Title" to show the title for marker(using "google-maps-utility-library-v3"). But marker needs title value. Because marker is used internally to identify the "Title". 
Should I ask to google maps developer about it?
Sombody help me. I tried, but I couldn't found an answer it..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide your Title in info window, you could use CSS to do the job.

`.bubbleContainer h3{
     display:none;
}`

It will hide Title when you click and open info window Or you could javascript to trigger it.